# Rectangle detection on noisy image Python

Tags: python, image-processing

guys!

I'm trying to detect rectangles lines on this very noisy image. So far I was able to detect the first Rectangle and the outside rectangle. But I not able to find the inner rectangles. Any help to my problem? Thank you so much!

```
# import the necessary packages
import cv2
import numpy as np
# Read image
img = cv2.imread('test8_2.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) # road.png is the filename
# Convert the image to gray-scale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Find the edges in the image using canny detector
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 60, 120)
# Detect points that form a line
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 15, minLineLength=10, maxLineGap=40)
# Draw lines on the image
for line in lines:
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 3)
# Show result
cv2.imshow("Result Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OpAb.png)
[input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqsDp.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding the pixel values horizontally, you obtain a 1D profile. Then smoothing this profile vertically with a gaussian, you obtain a clean signal from which you can detect the minima/maxima and you can estimate the position of the edges.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi! 
Thank so much for your answer! How did you get to this image? I didn't understand how you added the pixel horizontally and then smoothed with gaussian?

Comment: @Ruben: what don't you understand more specifically ?

Comment: I'm able to add the pixels horizontally, but how do I smooth it with the gaussian filter, what were the value range did you use for the green lines? And also how do I estimate the edges with the maximas and minimas?

Comment: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHwlv.png]Pixels_Plot

Comment: @Ruben: OpenCV or numpy must have a 1D gaussian filter. I adjusted the lines by hand, but you already know the global rectangle. On this profile, a maximum can be safely detected as a short increasing section followed by a short decreasing one, and similar for minimum.

Comment: I was able to do the gaussian filter implementation, also finding the maximas and minimas ([https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKIpF.png]) But the question is, with the maximas and minimas how I find the edges? And would you mind sharing your code with me? Thanks

Comment: Very nice. The edges are "somewhere" between the maxima and minima (in fact at the inflection points, but the extrema of the derivative will probably be unreliable). Try taking the points where the values are halfway between two extrema. I have no source code.